# Can't Deserialize DateTime to local time using JsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, azure, datetime

I need to store an event time in Azure Table Storage. That time has to be in the users local time, not UTC....really. [The data is queried like "Find me all the purchases that occurred on (the users) Saturday". Obviously "Saturday" represents a large range of time for global users, and I can't query by each user by timezone separately].

The data comes in from an Event Hub in Json. The date property is a DateTime and it's set to DateTime.Now on the client (sending to the Event Hub). I'm using Newtonsoft JsonSerializer on both ends. I can't seem to get the date in local time form when deserializing. I've tried various forms of:

```
JsonSerializer jsDeserializer = new JsonSerializer();
jsDeserializer.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
```

I think it's best if the timezone info get stripped out and it seems like it's been a common enough problem and there are enough properties to JsonSerializer to handle it...but no luck so far. Do I need to write a custom converter? Or do I have to stringify it?

To those comments:

- I don't want to know or care what the Json is. As stated, a C#
  DateTime property is set in the client to DateTime.Now and the Json
  serializer is called. On the server, the Json deserializer is called
  and a DateTime property is returned. In theory, I should never have
  to see the actual Json...that's kind of the point.
- I don't want to know or care what "my timezone" is. The Event Hub WebJob is
  running on Azure so I can't even guarantee what the timezone of the
  server will be.
- If the value of DateTime.Now is 5pm on the client in EDT, it always gets serialized => deserialized to 9pm. It needs to be stored in the DB as 5pm for querying purposes.

Comment: I think question is missing  sample json,  your timezone, expected output

Comment: In fact posting a good question is not complex. *I have this input, I wrote this code, I get this output, but expect this*

Answer (score 0):

Well, here are a couple ways to get it to work...

1) If you can change the client Jsonserializer, add the  DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified property to the JsonSerializerSettings.

2) If you can't change the client (I can't), then deserialize an object that has a DateTimeOffset type instead of the DateTime type. From there you can get the original local time (DateTimeOffset.DateTime).

```
        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());
        var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local,
        };
        List<ObjWithDateTimeOffset> eAcqs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ObjWithDateTimeOffset>>(data, jsonSerializerSettings);
        List<ObjWithDateTime> gAcqs = new List<ObjWithDateTime>();
        foreach(ObjWithDateTimeOffset eAcq in eAcqs)
        {
            ObjWithDateTime gAcq = new ObjWithDateTime()
            {
                AcquisitionType = eAcq.AcquisitionType,
                Value = eAcq.Value,
                DateAcquisition = eAcq.DateAcquisition.DateTime,
            };
            gAcqs.Add(gAcq);
        }
        return gAcqs;
```